# Issue on Display Resolution

Tags: hdmi, display, screen, pi-3b+, hot-plug

I am unable to set the correct screen resolution when trying to connect TV/Monitor(via HDMI) with RaspberryPi3 at runtime, the following are the steps:

1. Disconnect TV if already connected
2. Boot RaspberryPI
3. Wait till it boots
4. Connect TV with RaspberryPI

### I tried the following:

1. added lines in /boot/config.txt
   hdmi_force_hotplug=1
   hdmi_group=1
   hdmi_mode=16
2. Rebooted
3. It worked for a particular TV with the preferred settings
   I configured the mode and group based on the TV's configuration

The issue is when I connect (hot-plug) to different TV at runtime, the resolution is not proper.

I tried the command tvservice, etc. It didn't help either.

Is there is a way/command to set the Screen resolution for any TV at runtime?

Comment: You have tried `tvservice --explicit="CEA 16"` already?

Comment: @Janka: yes in my case the preferred setting is DMT 39, i tried the command as- tvservice -e "DMT 39 HDMI", also tried with "CEA 16 HDMI"

Comment: updated the answer in the following link:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81687/tv-display-resolution-issue-during-runtime