# TV display resolution issue during runtime

Tags: hdmi, raspbian-jessie, display, screen, hot-plug

when I tried to tvservice -e "CEA 16", the TV's screen always black-out.

Whether the option is not supported or is it a bug. I am currently, running RASPBIAN NON-NOOBS and running 4.8.16 kernel. Will upgrading to a new kernel can solve this issue.

I tried for long time that I could not able to figure out, my requirement is to set the Screen resolution during runtime( i.e, hotplugging different monitor's or screen)

Any information is of a great help.

Comment: What make and model of TV are you connecting to ? Are you using hdmi? I would alway suggest using the latest fully updated Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the following resolution solved my issue

The steps are as follows:

```
- tvservice -p ( the entire goes blank, looks like the TV is OFF ) 
   or
  tvservice -e "CEA 16" or "DMT 39" --> based on the configuration.
- Change the terminal screen from tty7 ( desktop ) to tty1
- Again change the terminal screen from tty1 to tty7.
- The Resolution issue is solved.
```

The following script helped me:

```
tvservice -p
sudo chvt 1
sudo chvt 7
```